# How to restore functionality to Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7

I have WinXP in Virtual PC in Win7. It used to worked OK. Now launching V.P.C. starts, but stops, then tries again and stops, and no longer reaches the completion stage. What can I do to restore its functionality ?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried reinstalling and it still doesn't work then, most probably, your computer doesn't meet the required prerequisites for it to function. Read this article to learn more about what you need in order for this piece of software to function without problems:

[Windows Virtual PC - Prerequisites & Installation Guide](http://www.7tutorials.com/windows-virtual-pc-prerequisites-installation-guide)